# Submitting Select Option Value in Angular Material

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, angular-material

**HTML:**

```
<form id="reg" name="reg" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="http://api.phphotspot.com/v-2/client-register" method="post">
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
         <label for="country">Country</label>       
         <md-select name="country"  ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}" id="country" ng-model="signupFormData.country" placeholder="Select a Country">
            <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in countries">{{opt.name}}</md-option >
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-button ng-submit class="md-raised md-primary">Register</md-button>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    angular.module('signUpNewUser', ['ngMaterial'])
        .controller('signUpFormController', function($scope) {
             $scope.signupFormData = {};
             $scope.countries = [
                   {id:"AU", name:"Australia"},
                   {id:"BR", name:"Brazil"},
                   {id:"CA", name:"Canada"},
                   {id:"IT", name:"Italy"},
                   {id:"GB", name:"United Kingdom"},
                   {id:"US", name:"United States"}];
            });
</script>
```

I want to submit the selected country when user clicks the button. For an example when the user selects the country Australia and submits, in the server side `$_POST['country']` should be equal to *"AU"*. But currently `$_POST['country']` becomes a string *"Object"* instead of *"AU"*.

Can someone help me to fix that?

---

I changed the **html** to,

```
<form id="reg" name="reg" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="http://api.phphotspot.com/v-2/client-register" method="post">
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
         <label for="country">Country</label>       
         <md-select name="country"  ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value'}" id="country" ng-model="signupFormData.country" placeholder="Select a Country">
            <md-option ng-value="opt.id" ng-repeat="opt in countries">{{opt.name}}</md-option >
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-button ng-submit class="md-raised md-primary">Register</md-button>
</form>
```

Now there is a strange behavior. When I var_dump the `$_POST` value in php I get,

```
array (size=1)
  '_country' => string '? string:AU ?' (length=13)
```

An underscore is added to the name of the field..! Also the value is still not the expected "AU".

Answer (score 1):

Use `opt.id` instead of just `opt` for your `ng-value`, as that holds the value you want to post.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. But still that doesn't work. There is a strange behaviour. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

For the first half of your question (about the value not being correct), I'm not completely sure my suggestion will help.  It's possible that if you take the suggestion below, it might help.  It comes through correctly when I look at the data that comes back when I do it the way I explain.

In regards to the preceding underscore, I had a similar thing happen with me, too, and I couldn't find the solution online anywhere.  I personally fixed this by adding a hidden input box with the value I wanted in it, using even the same `name` attribute as on the original input box, and it posted without the underscore.

For example:

```js
angular
    .module('app', ['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('DemoController', DemoController);

DemoController.$inject = [];

function DemoController() {
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.options = [
        {id: 45, name: 'Massachusetts'},
        {id: 46, name: 'Alaska'},
        {id: 47, name: 'Virginia'},
        {id: 48, name: 'Utah'},
        {id: 49, name: 'Florida'}
    ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.7/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.7/angular-material.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DemoController as vm">
  <form>
    <label>A few random states:</label>
    <md-select ng-model="vm.selected" aria-label="Random States">
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in vm.options | orderBy: 'name'" ng-value="option.id">{{ option.name }}</md-option>
    </md-select>
    
    <!-- Hidden input holding the value I want to send to the form -->
    <input type="hidden" name="state" ng-value="vm.selected">
    
    <!-- The posting of forms isn't all that great of a thing on a StackOverflow page, so I'll let you just test that on your own. -->
  </form>
</div>
```

If you want to, you can inspect the result to see that the hidden input has what you want in it, and it should also post with the `name` that you wanted it to have without the underscore.